# Common methods and operators for inline classes used as units of measurement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am playing with the idea of using Kotlin's inline classes to express type-safe operations with units of measurement. For example, let's define units for distance, time and speed:

```
inline class Meters(val v: Float) {
    operator fun plus(other: Meters) = Meters(v + other.v)
    operator fun times(amount: Float) = Meters(v * amount)
    operator fun compareTo(other: Meters) = v.compareTo(other.v)
    operator fun div(other: Meters): Float = v / other.v

    fun calcSpeed(time: Seconds) = MetersPerSecond(v * time.v)
    // operator fun times(time: Seconds) = MetersPerSecond(v / time.v) // clash (for now?)
}

inline class Seconds(val v: Float) {
    operator fun plus(other: Seconds) = Seconds(v + other.v)
    operator fun times(amount: Float) = Seconds(v * amount)
    operator fun compareTo(other: Seconds) = v.compareTo(other.v)
    operator fun div(other: Seconds): Float = v / other.v

    fun calcSpeed(distance: Meters) = MetersPerSecond(distance.v / v)
}

inline class MetersPerSecond(val v: Float) {
    operator fun plus(other: MetersPerSecond) = MetersPerSecond(v + other.v)
    operator fun times(amount: Float) = MetersPerSecond(v * amount)
    operator fun compareTo(other: MetersPerSecond) = v.compareTo(other.v)

    fun calcDistance(time: Seconds) = Meters(v * time.v)
    fun calcTime(distance: Meters) = Seconds(distance.v / v)
}
```

The idea here is to define methods for operations that either:

1. Leave the unit unchanged (eg: sum, multiplication for a pure
   value)
2. Result in a pure value (eg: division by value of the same
   unit)
3. Result in a value of another defined unit (eg: `time * distance = speed`)

So that one can write expressions like:

```
val distance = Meters(1f)
val time = Seconds(1f)
val speed: MetersPerSecond = (distance * 0.5f).calcSpeed(time)
```

Looking at the operators in the example which fall into cases 1 and 2, I can clearly see a pattern, and I am wondering whether there is a way to define those methods once in a more generic fashion for all types that need this "unit-of-measurement" behavior.

I thought about having a common interface and defining operators as extension functions with generics:

```
interface UnitOfMeasurement { val v: Float }
operator fun <T: UnitOfMeasurement> T.plus(other: T) = T(v + other.v)
```

But of course this won't work because I can't instantiate a generic like that. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a factory function of measurement units, that is reified on type T. Then you use it in your operators:

```
interface UnitOfMeasurement { val v: Float }

inline class Meter(override val v: Float) : UnitOfMeasurement

inline class Second(override val v: Float) : UnitOfMeasurement

inline fun <reified T : UnitOfMeasurement> create(v: Float): T {
    return when (T::class) {
        Meter::class -> Meter(v) as T
        Second::class -> Second(v) as T
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("don't know how to create ${T::class}")
    }
}

inline operator fun <reified T : UnitOfMeasurement> T.plus(other: T) = create<T>(v + other.v)

fun main() {
    val a = Meter(10f)
    val b = Meter(5f)
    println(a + b)
    
    val c = Second(60f)
    val d = Second(30f)
    println(c + d)
    
    // println(a + c) // throws IllegalArgumentException
}
```

Can be tried [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)